# Have to speak pre-written sentences

Tags: android, speech-synthesis, accessibility

I am looking for an Android app you could use to list sentences like you can in Google Keep and then select any sentence and press a button to have it spoken out.

This could also among other things helpful for a deaf or unable to speak person (eg. on a trip who could write but had a really bad accent) convey what they wanted to say to the listener.

Comment: What language(s)?

Answer (score 1):

There is an app called [YASFA](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.yasfa.views) on F-Droid that lets you write some predefined words or sentences and upon clicking them it plays them out.

The app also comes with some predefined words that are useful for people in their daily life.

You can write your own sentences and save them.

The app is very light weight around 1.5 MB only.It works only with English language.

You can download the apk from their site or install it from [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/) client for Android

Hope this helps your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

[SynWrite](http://uvviewsoft.com/) text editor has plugin "Speech": install it in AddonsManager. Then select any text block and call plugin.

And you can put call to "speech" at toolbar. Make toolbar item.

It uses Windows API for it.

Comment: Sorry but I was looking for an Android app.